# HTTP Connection header

Tags: http, networking, tcp, http-headers, network-programming

According to the [Mozilla Developer docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Connection), the `Connection` header controls whether the network connection stays open after the current transaction finishes.

I am unable to understand that, what from the TCP side is the mechanism which checks for the value of the HTTP `Connection` header, and provides the necessary functionality. How is this implemented in the network stack?

Answer (score 0):

It's the other way around.

TCP has no awareness of HTTP. The client and server establish a TCP connection between them to exchange HTTP messages. So both of them also can tear it down. The reason for closing the connection could be the HTTP messages they receive or any other consideration.